# fullpage.js: Fade in slides with css

Tags: css, fullpage.js

I am trying to change the action of the slides. instead of slides moving i would like to have them fade in.

At the same time keep the sections the same, so they will continue to move as normal.

I have added the following over riding the default but it does not seem to take effect:

CSS:

```
 .fp-slidesContainer {
    width: 100%!important;
    transform: none!important;
}

.fp-slide {
    width: 100%!important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.fp-slide.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://www.ahimsainvestments.com - The rest of the parallax still operates as normal

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by using the [Fading Effect extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fading-effect.html).

You'll have to use the latest parallax version (0.0.9) and the latest fading effect version (0.0.6). Then use `parallax: 'sections'` and `fadingEffect: 'slides'`.